# BLE(Bluetooth Low Energy) sync issue on some android phones

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am creating an APP in which I need to sync the data from pedometer(Bluetooth 4.0). I took reference from Android sample BLE project.
It's working fine with most of the devices but in some model like XIAOMI MI5 and some samsung models like E7 I am facing issue where BluetoothGattCallback  functions are not getting called.

Sometimes If I connect pedometer with other APP and then reconnect it with my APP it starts working.
   I am unable to find where is the problem.What is the best way to make it work on all supported phones?

Answer (score 0):

You can print some log in method onConnectionStateChange of BluetoothGattCallback so that you can confirm whether your bluetooth connection state is connecting.

Comment: I already did ,And as I mentioned BluetoothGattCallback methods are not getting called

Comment: Maybe when I got a MI5, I can test it .